# glm set object position

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math, coordinate-transformation

I want to set the **x, y, z coordinates** of the object (not a camera) using glm library in OpenGL. 
I expect  `glm::translate` method to cope with that, but it generates the matrix, that actually modifies the way I look at my object.

That is the way a call the method:

```
glm::translate(glm::vec3(x, y, z));
```

And it returns the matrix:

```
| 1  0  0  0 |
| 0  1  0  0 |
| 0  0  1  0 |
| x  y  z  1 |
```

But I expect:

```
| 1  0  0  x |
| 0  1  0  y |
| 0  0  1  z |
| 0  0  0  1 |
```

I made a quick-fix like `glm::transpose(glm::translate(glm::vec3(x, y, z)))`, but it seems to be a bad code.

Is there a way to generate a matrix that would create a parallel translation, that would set the object's x, y, z coordinates, **without** transposing the matrix itself?

[image: See this picture]

Comment: I think you print or use your matrix incorrectly.

Comment: I think use function like this 
```mat4 m;
m = glm::translate(m, glm::vec3(x , y, z));```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GLM creates column major order matrices, because GLSL creates column major order matrices.

If you want to get a row major order matrix, then you have either to `glm::transpose` the matrix or you have to use a matrix initializer:

```
glm::mat4 m = glm::mat4(
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, x,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, y,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, z,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0 );
```

See [OpenGL Mathematics (GLM)](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/index.html):

> OpenGL Mathematics (GLM) is a header only C++ mathematics library for graphics software based on the OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL) specifications.

See [The OpenGL Shading Language 4.6, 5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors, page 101](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf):

> To initialize a matrix by specifying vectors or scalars, the components are assigned to the matrix elements in **column-major order**.
>
> ```
> mat4(float, float, float, float,  // first column
>      float, float, float, float,  // second column
>      float, float, float, float,  // third column
>      float, float, float, float); // fourth column
> ```

See also [OpenGL Mathematics (GLM); 2. Vector and Matrix Constructors](http://www.c-jump.com/bcc/common/Talk3/Math/GLM/GLM.html#W01_0020_vector_and_matrix_con)